# What is the usefulness of cycles of f(x) in Pollard's rho factorization?

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization

I've been getting myself acquainted with the Pollard Rho factorization from this page: http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~srirams/classes/doku.php/pollard_rho_tutorial.

I think I understood well almost everything that has been said, but one thing I'm confused about - the fact that we use f(x) = x^2 + a mod N to generate pseudo-random numbers for checking.

What is the usefulness of iterating f(x) and it's cycles?

Comment: Actually, the discussion on this thread is much more detailed about why f(x)= x^2 + a mod N works "better". https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.crypt/yMVIKpYk5_Q

Comment: @SriramS So are you the actual author of that tutorial? :) I just want to say that I think the text is well written and very easy to follow. I'm just not sure how these cycles are utilized. I'll check the link you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I made that page for my students. One of my students saw your post and sent me it's link as soon as it was posted.  My page is not meant to be a rigorous presentation. For that I recommend the Algorithms book by Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest.

Comment: Already found it. Thanks again!